# Bound on $(A+B)^k$ for positive symmetric definite matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-definite

When $a$ and $b$ are positive numbers and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, one has the bound
$$
(a+b)^{2k} \leq 2^{2k} (a^{2k} + b^{2k}),
$$
which can be proven for instance by bounding $a+b \leq \max(a,b)$.

I am curious whether a similar bound holds for psd (symmetric and positive semi-definite) matrices $A$ and $B$.  That is, does it hold that
$$
(A+B)^{2k} \leq 2^{2k} (A^{2k} + B^{2k})?
$$

In the case for example that $k=1$ I believe one can modify the proof of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality:
$$
2(A^2 + B^2) - (A+B)^2 = A^2 - AB - BA + B^2 = (A-B)^2.
$$
The matrix on the right is positive semidefinite because it is a square, and therefore
$$
0 \leq 2(A^2 + B^2) - (A+B)^2,
$$
which can be rearranged to
$$
(A+B)^2 \leq 2 (A^2 + B^2).
$$

I believe an induction can be done in the case that $k$ is a power of $2$, but I am curious if this bound holds for arbitrary $k$, ideally avoiding induction (just because I am interested in the shortest possible proof, if it exists).

Comment: For $X,Y$ symmetric definite positive, how do you define $X \color{red}{\ge} Y$?

Comment: $X\geq Y$ if $X - Y$ is positive semidefinite, or in other words if $u^TX u \geq u^TYu$ for all vectors $u$.